# Add php variable into Wordpress custom menu

Tags: wordpress, cookies, themes

I've been trying to figure out how to add a php variable into my WP navigation links.
Let me explain:
I'm gonna set a cookie on the very first page of my website, when the user clicks on one of 4 types of profile:
-family
-pro
-seniors
-cadres

Currently, I have a theme switcher extension wich modifies the WP theme depending on those prefixes:

```html
http://mywebsite.com/family
http://mywebsite.com/pro
http://mywebsite.com/seniors
http://mywebsite.com/cadres
... etc
```

The colors & content of the 4 "home" pages are different, but I'm using the WP navigation menu (wich remains the same on every page, so the prefixes disappear when clicking on its links).

Initially, I wanted to modify my menu links like that:

```html
https://mywebsite.com<?php if (isset($_COOKIE['profil'])){echo '/'.$_COOKIE['profil'];} else{} ?>/navigation-link1
```

Here:
[menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDXHP.png)

But I can't add php here, and the solution is not ideal because it would only apply to the menu, and not the posts permalinks (I want some posts to be available regardless the profile and I don't want to duplicate all my posts).

Ideally, I would like to have a solution to set the WP theme directly based on the stored cookie. This way, it would also apply when the users click on a post permalink.

I've read things about a "walker" but I don't know what it is, wp_nav_menu_objects, but I didn't understand what files to modify nor wich code to use.

I always search the web to find my answers, but I'm french and I think my understanding has reach it's limits, so if somebody could take the time to explain to me like I'm 4 years old :), I would be grateful.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to manage that situation with cookies instead through the URL the user is seeing?

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. Its because I can't change all of the url's of my website, since some articles/post/pages will be available for every profile. And I want to remember the user's favorite profile, so that he doesnt have to choose each time. There willbe a redirection to http://mywebsite.com/family if a cookie profil=family exists